# How to prevent retrieving Private Lists in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, subscriber, publicationlist

I'm trying to retrieve Subscriber's public lists only, but it keeps returning public lists + **a private list called "All Subscribers"**. I've tried both following methods but neither worked, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

METHOD 1:

```
var subLists = subObj.Lists.Retrieve({
                Property: "Type",
                SimpleOperator: "equals",
                Value: "Public"
             })
```

METHOD 2:

```
var subLists = subObj.Lists.Retrieve({
                  LeftOperand: {
                      Property: 'ListClassification',
                      SimpleOperator: 'equals',
                      Value: 'PublicationList'
                  },
                  LogicalOperator: 'AND',
                  RightOperand: {
                      Property: 'Type',
                      SimpleOperator: 'equals',
                      Value: 'Public'
                  }
              })
```

Comment: I know next to nothing about SFMC, but at least for ruling out purposes can you add (however it should actually be written) `"Type"` `"does not equal"` `"Private"` and see what you get?

Comment: I already tried: "Type" "notEquals" "Private" too. It didn't work either :(

Comment: Oh, well.  It was worth a shot.  I thought that's all I had, but here's one more: Are you certain that there is not also a Public list called "All Subscribers" that is being returned?  It sounds to me that that would be an OOB one.

Comment: I console.log() all the returned lists, there is only one "All Subscribers" list whose type is "Private"